# Interceptor - Token - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-http-interceptors

I am new in AngularJS and I am having a problem with the interceptor that I created and the restAPI.

The interceptor code is this:

```
factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function ($q, $location, $localStorage) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($localStorage.token) {
                config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
            }
            console.log($localStorage.token);
            console.log(config);
            return config;
        },
        'responseError': function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}]);
```

and my calls from the rest api that I created are similar to this:

```
$http.get('/api/producto/', {headers: {'x-access-token': $localStorage.token}})
            .success(function (data) {                    
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
```

If I send the {headers: {'x-access-token': $localStorage.token}} to the $http the restapi works as fine but if I remove this it fails with Error 403 (Forbidden)

I decided to add this in the all GET apis but for POST it is not working as I expected. My POST api looks like this:

```
var formData = {
        cliente: $scope.newCliente,
        headers: {'x-access-token': $localStorage.token}
    };

    $http.post('/api/cliente', formData)
        .success(function (data) {
            ....
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
```

What I am doing wrong? What should I change in my interceptor in order to not send the headers in GET or POST operations?

Comment: in interceptor you are setting Authorisation Header but in GET request you make, you are setting x-access-token. set the header you want(x-access-token) in the interceptor

Comment: OMG you are right thanks a lot it works now :)